# codeception, How to add full site_url in url parameter in config

Tags: php, symfony, codeception

Current configuration.

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - REST:
            url: /
            depends: Symfony
```

I want configuration like below.

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - REST:
            url: dailyNotes.up // have any option for add url here. currently 404 error returns
            depends: Symfony
```

I must need site url for test, Api need site url so that codeception url must need to set.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Having different url in your configuration depending on the environment (one for the prod and dev, and one for the test, for example)?

Comment: No same url, but i have check request host in api but it's not found there.

Comment: Can you post some code to show your issue? It's difficult to understand what you're trying to do. :/

Comment: i want to add host url in configuration.

Comment: using http://dailyNotes.up in my local system i can access my project. same way i want to add http://dailyNotes.up in URL parameter.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. dailyNotes.up is a local project on your PC and you want to access it via another local project (the one you want to configure), is that right?

Comment: If you want to set a full url, it must start with `http://`, right?

Answer (score 1):

For production I guess it won't change every day so you could consider just creating parameter that will hold site root url part and put it there manually or...

You can try something called Expression Language in Symfony and inject service method result directly into config file as a service argument. For example I do the same thing in service config file:

```
redirectUri: "@=service('router').generate('any_route_your_heart_desire', {}, 0)"
```

As a third argument of the route service you can just pass here one of the constants values from UrlGeneratorInterface.

Here you have a link to the docs:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html

I hope it will help you.

Cheers!

Comment: good one solution for get site url. Thanks. But it's not my problem. config not allow full url here.

Comment: it's give 404 error. due to not allowed url here. Here url option only for give segment not site url

Comment: So u want something like url: http://myfullurl.me... and it gives back 404 - so it's not found error - url is correct?

Comment: yes url is correct. but codeception not allow url here while using depends : symfony

Comment: For now I don't have any more ideas. Since I'm not familiar with Codeception I guess it will be blind shot but... https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/2402 maybe this will help in any way?

Comment: @UttamPanara Do you still have issue yet? I am doing the exactly the same thing as my testing url is different per environment and trying to find the solution.

In fact, my issue wasn't about the url, I was able to use full url fine